# Geometry of syntomic cohomology

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, p-adic-hodge-theory

Deligne cohomology has a geometric interpretation. For example, $H^{2}_{\mathcal{D}}(X,\mathbb{Z}(1))$ is identified with the group $H^{1}(X,\mathcal{O}_{X}^{\ast})$ of isomorphism classes of line bundles on $X$, and $H^{2}_{\mathcal{D}}(X,\mathbb{Z}(2))$ is identified with the group $\mathbb{H}^{1}(X,\mathcal{O}_{X}^{\ast}\xrightarrow{d\log}\Omega^{1}_{X})$ of isomorphism classes of line bundles on $X$ with connection. For the general case see [Gaj97] where the description is in terms of iterated classifying spaces.

Syntomic cohomology is a $p$-adic analogue of Deligne cohomology. Does it have a geometric interpretation along similar lines?

[Gaj97] P. Gajer, *Geometry of Deligne cohomology*, Invent. Math. 127 (1997), no.1, 155-207.

Comment: I'm not an expert but this may help you. As far as I know, when we say that *syntomic cohomology is a p-adic analogue of Deligne cohomology*, we are saying (at least in particular) that syntomic cohomology and p-adic Abel-Jacoby share the same relations as we can observe between the Deligne cohomology and the Abel-Jacoby map.

Comment: This is something I've read in the introduction of this paper https://webusers.imj-prg.fr/~jan.nekovar/pu/syn.pdf

Comment: @MarsaultChabat Certainly. Indeed there are many reasons to say that syntomic cohomology is a $p$-adic analogue of Deligne cohomology. But that is not my question.

Comment: Note that I was purposefully rather vague in my question. For example, I didn't specify which "flavour" of syntomic cohomology I mean. I would guess that Besser's rigid syntomic approach might be most likely to have a description somewhat similar to the interpretations of Deligne cohomology in my question, but I don't know.